# "This is not a perpetual motion machine, because reservoir temperatures are changing." Is it a valid argument?

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature, perpetual-motion

I've already faced this situation several times: given a statement (in area of thermodynamics) I used it to provide an example of some perpetual motion machine (of first or second kind). Therefore, I thought, proving the initial statement wrong. And sometimes I get a response that I haven't actually constructed a perpetual motion machine. Because the temperature reservoirs I use will eventually change their temperatures. Ergo, my construction is not perpetual.

I'm pretty sure that the argument is invalid (not to say -- silly). But I still can be wrong.

Whatever the case. I'd like to have a consistent way of rejecting  it (or accepting and using it)  starting from first principles and definitions of thermodynamics. References dealing with that argument are also welcome.

Comment: Isn't the essence of a perpetual motion machine that at the end of some cycle, work has been done but the machine has fully returned to it's original state?

Comment: @Kostya please could you illustrate the question with a specific example, which will help any answerers give you better answers?

Comment: two infinite reservoirs will allow a perpetual motion machine, because at the end of a Carnot cycle the system will have not changed and you have net work